# Yubikey with gpg2

Tags: gnupg, yubikey

I recently purchased a Yubikey 4, which is working great for U2F and a static password, but I'd like to use the PGP Smartcard functionality as well, so I connected the Yubikey to my computer and checked if it was recognized, by running `gpg2 --card-status`, which does not work, more on this later. I then tried `gpg --card-status`, which does work, but doesn't help me much because gpg and gpg2 have different keyrings so I can't use gpg(without 2) to transfer my private key.

The error message:

```
[jcgruenhage@greensp3 ~]$ gpg2 --card-status
gpg: error getting version from 'scdaemon': No SmartCard daemon
gpg: OpenPGP card not available: No SmartCard daemon
```

Correct output:

```
[jcgruenhage@greensp3 ~]$ gpg --card-status 
Application ID ...: D2760001240102010006042634800000
Version ..........: 2.1
Manufacturer .....: unknown
Serial number ....: 04263480
Name of cardholder: [not set]
Language prefs ...: [not set]
Sex ..............: unspecified
URL of public key : [not set]
Login data .......: [not set]
Private DO 1 .....: [not set]
Private DO 2 .....: [not set]
Signature PIN ....: not forced
Key attributes ...: 2048R 2048R 2048R
Max. PIN lengths .: 127 127 127
PIN retry counter : 3 0 3
Signature counter : 0
Signature key ....: [none]
Encryption key....: [none]
Authentication key: [none]
General key info..: [none]
```

Is there any way to get gpg2 to use scdaemon instead of gpg?
In case this is necessary: I'm using Fedora 23 on a Surface Pro 3.

Comment: Not relevant anymore, it works fine on fedora 24, with gpg and gpg2 as well

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify: gpg is an alias for binary.

```
gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG/MacGPG2) 2.2.8
```

To use you Yubikey as smart card, you can follow one of this guides:
https://developers.yubico.com/PIV/Guides/SSH_with_PIV_and_PKCS11.html
or
http://www.engineerbetter.com/blog/yubikey-ssh/

I have the same problem as you described with **GPG 2.1** and **2.2.9** from repo, so only **GPG 2.2.8** works fine for me.

Comment: `gpg` may be a link to `gpg2` for you, but that's not the case for others.

Comment: The main question is: what version was used, but not which symlink.

Answer (score 0):

I hit this problem this morning.

I run Debian Linux 11 (Bullseye), which ships with GnuPG 2.2.27; I found I needed to install the `scdaemon` package separately (from the Debian repositories).